# do not include AcmeDemoBundle using symfony installer

Tags: php, symfony

Using the symfony installer, how can I do to not include the AcmeDemoBundle.

The symfony installer does not interact with the user after the download is completed, so why they do include the option --no-interaction in the help?

The version am using is
`Symfony Installer version 0.5.0`

Comment: Please limit yourself to [one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Comment: You also ask, "the symfony installer does not interact with the user after the download is completed, so why they do include the option --no-interaction in the help?"

Comment: I personally liked the ***symfon*** and ***do not include*** part of the title :)

Comment: READ THE DOCUMENTATION: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html

Answer (score 2):

`--no-interaction` means, that the script is knowing that it's invoked not by a user who can interact with it, so any stdin readings should be skipped.

When you setup symfony you're done and will deploy it then. Do you start 10 projects a day and it is annoying?

Comment: It's actually just a `rm -rf src/Acme && sed -i '/Acme/d' app/AppKernel.php` if it's that hard for you :) (didn't test it)

Comment: Almost! You need to remove the `_acme_demo` routing declaration from `routing_dev.yml` too.